# Mostrar em json uma relationship

Tags: json, laravel

Eu estou fazendo um sistema que existe um cadastro de produtos, esses produtos o mesmo podem fazer parte de apenas um grupo, ou não.

Tenho esse model para Produtos:

```
    class Products extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['nome', 'codigo', 'preco'];

        protected $hidden = ['id'];

        public function Groups()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\pGroup', 'produto_id', 'id');
        }
    }
```

E esse model onde eu armazeno os produtos que tem um grupo

```
class pGroup extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['group_id', 'produto_id'];

    public function Group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductGroup');
    }
}
```

Nesse model pGroup eu apenas salvo o id do produto e o id do grupo como uma foreign key.

Agora, vamos para o controller dos produtos.

```
public function find($nome){
    $locate= Products::where('nome', 'like', "$nome%")->with('groups.group')->get();

    return response()->json($locate, 200);
}
```

Como podem ver, aparenta estar tudo certo. O problema é que no json ele cria duas arrays de objetos, uma "Groups" ele puxa os dados da tabela pGroup, que é uma tabela que contem apenas os ids referenciados e no outro objeto "Group" ele puxa os dados que eu quero, que é o nome desse grupo.

Como eu faço para que seja exibido apenas um objeto contendo o nome do grupo em que o produto está, passando pela foreign key.

Comment: se tem que fazer um inner join então!

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse trecho da documentação e creio que pode te ajudar criando relacionamentos com o "HasMany": https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through